# If the cadinality of $X$ is infinite, then the elements of $X/ \sim$ are also of infinite cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X$ a set and $\sim$ and an equivalence relation on $X$. If the cadinality of $X$ is infinite, then the elements of $X/ \sim$ are also of infinite cardinality. (True or False)

I don't know how I could verify or contradict this "conjecture". Is anyone is able to give me a hint to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you considered what happens with some very easy equivalence relations? If you consider the two "trivial" ones you might get your answer.

Comment: A hint in a different direction from Brian's: what if ~ is the relation 'shares parity with' on the integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: What if $\sim$ is the relation of equality?